# Using Fourier Transform to get frequency and phase

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Suppose I have samples of a periodic function, what is a good way to get frequency and phase information out of it?

In particular, I'd like to get a form like

```
a+b Cos[c x + d]
```

Here's a part of the sample

```
{255,255,255,249,64,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,233,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,209,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,118,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,132,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,200,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,239,19,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,46,245,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,186,0}
```

Comment: Nice to see you again! WRT your Q: Why do you want to fit a `Cos[ ]` there?

Comment: Well, just trying to figure out how to get the phase of the signal. It comes out of calibration picture in book scanning

Comment: For the frequency you could do an autocorrelation, and then detect maxima and minima. The autocorrelation works better if you trim your your points at both edges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Using Autocorrelation and FindFit[ ]

```
(*Your list*)
ListPlot@l
```

[image]

```
(*trim the list*)
l1 = Drop[l, (First@Position[l, 0])[[1]] - 1];
l2 = Drop[l1, Length@l1 - (Last@Position[l1, 0])[[1]] - 1];
(*autocorrelate*)
ListLinePlot@(ac = ListConvolve[l2, l2, {1, 1}])
```

[image]

```
(*Find Period by taking means of maxs and mins spacings*)
period = Mean@
   Join[
    Differences@(maxs = Table[If[ac[[i - 1]] < ac[[i]] > ac[[i + 1]], i, 
                               Sequence @@ {}], {i, 2, Length@ac - 1}]), 
    Differences@(mins = Table[If[ac[[i - 1]] > ac[[i]] < ac[[i + 1]], i, 
                               Sequence @@ {}], {i, 2, Length@ac - 1}])];

(*Show it*)
Show[ListLinePlot[(ac = ListConvolve[l2, l2, {1, 1}]), 
  Epilog -> 
   Inset[Framed[Style["Mean Period = " <> ToString@N@period, 20], 
     Background -> LightYellow]]], 
 Graphics[Join[{Arrowheads[{-.05, .05}]}, {Red}, 
   Sequence @@@ Arrow[{{{#[[1]], Min@ac}, {#[[2]], Min@ac}}}] & /@ 
    Partition[mins, 2, 1], {Blue}, 
   Sequence @@@ Arrow[{{{#[[1]], Max@ac}, {#[[2]], Max@ac}}}] & /@ 
    Partition[maxs, 2, 1]]]]
```

[image]

```
(*Now let's fit the Cos[ ] to find the phase*)
model = a + b Cos[x (2 Pi)/period + phase];
ff = FindFit[l, model, {a, b, phase}, x, 
             Method -> NMinimize, MaxIterations -> 100];

(*Show results*)
Show[ListPlot[l, PlotRange -> All, 
  Epilog -> 
   Inset[Framed[Style["Phase = " <> ToString@N@(phase /. ff), 20], 
     Background -> LightYellow]]], Plot[model /. ff, {x, 1, 100}]]
```

[image]

Comment: @Yaro the non-trivial thing is that you can't fit the trig function at once, you need to find the frequency first. I don't remember exactly why, but it happened to me before and found this two steps procedure far better

Answer (score 2):

Please look at `FourierDCT` [ref page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FourierDCT.html).

Your data looks very much like `SquareWave` function. By manual inspection it seems like your data fit `SquareWave[{0, 255}, (x + 5)/23 ]`.

[image]